# Trying To read data from data base using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to read an email Address from a database and send mail to the email.

Here is my code to read the email address:

```
$recipient = mysql_query("SELECT recipientEmail FROM flightStatus 
                          WHERE arrivalStatus = 'Landed'");
```

There is currently only one data in the database with the condition landed.

Using the phpMailer example to work around the mailing function so my mail function looks like this:

```
$mail->From     = "xxxx.yyyyy@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($recipient);
```

But I get message can't send message.

Comment: Do you plan to send emails to multiple people in ultimately?

Comment: Have you tried to output the email address before using it send an email. Pretty often the mail server is not set up correctly, which will give you a "can't send" message, too.

Comment: @opatut: he didn't even fetch the results, so it's not too surprising that it doesn't work the way he wants it to.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send a mail to mysql-resource. You have to 'fetch' the results first with eg. `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good link to get you started or to improve your mysql + php skills

[Database and other Animals](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641)

Note you will need to loop through your query result, even if you only have one entry in it because eventually you will have more than one entry

Answer (score 0):

`$recipient` is a resource ([mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)). To get to the selected `recipientEmail` you can use:

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT recipientEmail FROM flightStatus WHERE arrivalStatus = 'Landed'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($resource);

$mail->From = "...";
$mail->AddAdrress($row['recipientEmail']);
```

Comment: I think it's important to mention that it only adds the FIRST result to PHPMailer's AddAddress method. In case of multiple addresses, you have to add results with a while, for or foreach loop. By the way, in this case, I think it would be better to use $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); OR $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);, because it's maybe unneccessary to fetch results in a numerical way too.